# Chrome os, Chromebook, bash responds to every command in terminal with "permission denied" etc

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, mount, localhost

This is the 6th time I've written and attempted to post my problem and am about to go off my rocker,

I'm new to all this and an trying to install a Linux distro on my Chromebook but can't get started ib crosh, Below is a copy of the last exchange with crosh/bash, whatever. I've been slogging through this for over a week now and all I think I've learned is that I need to gain executive privilege to be able to get past this. But I don't even know what this last exchange is saying except that I can't do to my Chromebook what I want. Any suggestions would be great,

```
mount: PATH/TO/YOUR/FILE,: mount point does not exist.
chronos@localhost / $ sudo mount -o remount,rw -io exec PATH/TO/YOUR/
mount: PATH/TO/YOUR/: mount point does not exist.
chronos@localhost / $ crosh> shell
bash: shell: Permission denied
chronos@localhost / $ chronos@localhost / $ /usr/share/crosh/dev.d/50-crosh.sh
bash: chronos@localhost: command not found
chronos@localhost / $ bash: /usr/share/crosh/dev.d/50-crosh.sh: Permission denied
bash: bash:: command not found
chronos@localhost / $ chronos@localhost / $ sudo mount -o remount,rw -o exec PATH/TO/YOUR/FILE,
bash: chronos@localhost: command not found
chronos@localhost / $ 
chronos@localhost / $ We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
bash: We: command not found
chronos@localhost / $ Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:
bash: Administrator.: command not found
chronos@localhost / $ 
chronos@localhost / $     #1) Respect the privacy of others.
chronos@localhost / $     #2) Think before you type.
chronos@localhost / $     #3) With great power comes great responsibility.
chronos@localhost / $ 
chronos@localhost / $ mount: PATH/TO/YOUR/FILE,: mount point does not exist.
bash: mount:: command not found
chronos@localhost / $ chronos@localhost / $ sudo mount -o remount,rw -io exec PATH/TO/YOUR/
bash: chronos@localhost: command not found
chronos@localhost / $ mount: PATH/TO/YOUR/: mount point does not exist.
bash: mount:: command not found
chronos@localhost / $ chronos@localhost / $
```

Comment: It seems you tried to run commands like `chronos@localhost`, `We`, `Administrator.` etc. This doesn't make sense. Did you type or paste `We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System` as a command? If not, then it's not clear where it comes from. If yes, then what did you expect from running something that is obviously not a command? are you just pasting into terminal mindlessly? Please [edit] and clarify what exactly you did and what your goal is.

Comment: It looks like you're copying/typing in things other than commands, and also not making needed modifications before putting in the command. For instance, the `PATH/TO/YOUR/` part is clearly intended to be replaced by an actual path to a mount point or something similar. Long story short: you need to learn at least a little shell syntax so you can understand what you're reading, and not just blindly copy it without understanding it.

Comment: I can see that you are frustrated. Installing a Linux distribution on a Chromebook is **not** supported by Google or the device manufacturer and it is a **hacky and not consumer friendly** kind of thing. (It's also not upgrade safe, you may loose Linux data.) I've seen a lot of users coming by at AskUbuntu asking crazy things with the least context, all related to cargo cult Chromebook hype. I do love the devices and I own a few, but things need to be explained if you have no prior knowledge. This would be beyond FAQ style though. Can you please tell me where you have these instructions from?

Comment: I would have recommended to just get a Windows PC or laptop and install Linux on that… the good old fashioned way, but that can also be tricky. You best options to get a well supported Linux are https://puri.sm/ and https://system76.com/ — and https://endlessos.com/ for the non-tech savvy users.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo su 


localhost / $ df --output=target 

localhost / $ df --output=target /path/to/YOUR

localhost / $ sudo mount -o remount,rw  -io exec PATH/TO/YOUR/
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User! While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.